# Does angular ui select (bootstrap version) support optgroup?

Tags: angular-ui, optgroup, ui-select2

Does anyone know if Angular-Ui-Select Bootstrap version support an **`optgroup`**?

Can't seem to find any documentation for that on https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select?

Here is their example:

```
plnkr.co/edit/QCwSM75ilH2Vh6D9aMA4?p=preview
```

How to add an `optgroup`?

In this example, lets say, group persons by countries.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **group-by** attribute.

See "Demo Multiselect" (last example "Array of objects (with groupBy)") at
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

It's multiselect demo, but **group-by** works for single select too.

Answer (score 1):

This is group-by using string

**app.js:**

```
$scope.countries = [
                {
                    "code": "AD",
                    "name": "Andorra",
                    "continent": "Europe"
                },
                {
                    "code": "AE",
                    "name": "United Arab Emirates",
                    "continent": "Asia"
                },
                {
                    "code": "AF",
                    "name": "Afghanistan",
                    "continent": "Asia"
                }
            ];
```

**html:**

```
<div>
    <label>COUNTRY</label><br>
    <ui-select ng-model="user.country" style="min-width: 300px;">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Country">
            <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: {name: $select.search}" group-by="'continent'">
        <span ng-bind="country.name"></span>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

Generated JSON of all countries with their continent using

> http://peric.github.io/GetCountries/

Comment: Thank you so much! This works even in our old Angular 1.8 codebase.